# How to run "iwlist wlan0" on adb shell?

Tags: android, linux, adb, wifi

I am creating a code to run **iwlit** command on adb shell to obtain noise level of wifi. I tried to run the following command `iwlist wlan0 scanning`  but it shows the following output `127|emulator64_arm64:/ # iwlist wlan0 scanning                                                                                                                              /system/bin/sh: iwlist: inaccessible or not found` . Am I doing it in right way?

Comment: is iwlist in your PATH? Is it executable?

Comment: I a not sure but when I run "iw" on adb, it works.